# Cannot get UIButton to programmatically call action in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I cannot get my button to fire the associated method.  I am not using IB or anything like that (all programmatic).  The `_mainViewController` is passed in during custom init, just to clarify (although this should have nothing to do with the button).  Please see my code snips:

**viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CSNWZSSViewController : UIViewController

- (void)doneButtonPressed;

@property UIViewController *mainViewController;
@property UIButton *doneButton;

@end
```

**viewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _mainViewController.view.frame.size.width, 45)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    _doneButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_mainViewController.view.frame.size.width - 100, 0, 100, headerView.frame.size.height)];
    [_doneButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _doneButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:.77 blue:0 alpha:1];
    [headerView addSubview:_doneButton];

    CGRect headerLabelFrame = CGRectMake(5, 5, headerView.frame.size.width - 105, headerView.frame.size.height - 5);
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:headerLabelFrame];
    headerLabel.text = @"test header";
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f];
    headerLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    [self.view addSubview:headerView];
}

- (void)doneButtonPressed
{
    NSLog(@"button pressed");
}
```

**Update 10/9/16** *using buttonWithType init and explicit userInteractionEnabled*

```
_doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_doneButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_doneButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:.77 blue:0 alpha:1];
_doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(_mainViewController.view.frame.size.width - 100, 0, 100, headerView.frame.size.height);
_doneButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[headerView addSubview:_doneButton];
```

**Note 12/9/16** *the _mainViewController object is passed in here:*

```
CSNWZSSViewController *CSNWZSSVC = [[CSNWZSSViewController alloc] initWithRichTextString:source withTitleString:title forViewController:self.viewController];
[self.viewController.view addSubview:CSNWZSSVC.view];
```

**Solution with matt's help (see below)** *The context was getting messed up due to the lack of adding the new view controller.*

```
CSNWZSSViewController *CSNWZSSVC = [[CSNWZSSViewController alloc] initWithRichTextString:source withTitleString:title forViewController:self.viewController];
[self.viewController addChildViewController:CSNWZSSVC];
[self.viewController.view addSubview:CSNWZSSVC.view];
```

Comment: Can you try: `_doneButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` ?

Comment: @Randy ``userInteractionEnabled`` is true by default, and explicitly setting it had no affect unfortunately.  Please see updated code (10/9/16) above.

Comment: @matt yes, I can see the distinction of the button from it's parent view, ``headerView``.  The green showed up, the black (or any other color) works.  Still, the ``doneButtonPressed`` method is never called.  Please see updated code (10/9/16) above.

Comment: Is `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES` for your `headerView` as well ? I really don't think that would solve your problem, but we never know..

Comment: You could also try to set `_doneButton` above `headerLabel`. There might be some weird superposition. Could you try set a background color for `headerLabel` to see where this label is located exactly ?

Comment: @Randy yes, ``headerView`` does have ``userInteractionEnabled`` set to ``YES``.  It didn't make any difference either though.

Comment: @Randy okay, so I just completely commented out the ``headerLabel`` from the code, but it has made no difference to the button.

Comment: FWIW, I can change the button label for other states than ``UIControlStateNormal`` and it reflects the different labels such as ``UIControlStateHighlighted``.

Comment: @matt i'm sorry but I cannot do that due to the sensitivity of the app.

Comment: Another odd observation is that when looking at the button in "Debug View Hierarchy", the "Object Inspector" shows that the Target is ``NSNull`` and the Action is ``<nil>``.

Comment: Yup, my answer is right. You are not doing the child view controller dance correctly.

Comment: I don't mind if you down vote my question if you can justify your reasoning.  We need to encourage learning rather than trolling so arrogantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The _mainViewController is passed in during custom init

I'm going to guess that this is the problem — that you are mismanaging this view controller and that it is not being correctly made part of the view controller hierarchy, and in fact may even be going out of existence so that there is no one to send the button action message to.

**edit** Yes, now that you've posted more code, I'm clearly right:

```
CSNWZSSViewController *CSNWZSSVC = [[CSNWZSSViewController alloc] initWithRichTextString:source withTitleString:title forViewController:self.viewController];
[self.viewController.view addSubview:CSNWZSSVC.view];
```

That is totally wrong behavior.  You cannot arbitrarily add another view controller's view to yours. There is a strict dance for managing a child view controller, and you are not doing the dance.

Comment: this may be true.  Please see the **Note 12/9/16** above on how ``_mainViewController`` is passed in.  However, ``_mainViewController`` is only used within this class for dimensional purposes (albeit a little sloppy).

Comment: I rest my case.

Comment: I know this seems like a transcendence.  Could you teach me this dance?

Comment: Bravo!  Anyone interested in learning the dance ^^.  It's a very good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`UIButton *theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

And then set your frame.

Comment: I had this originally, but it made no difference.  I retried this with no avail.  Please see updated code (10/9/16) above.